# Android download multiple images

Tags: android

I need to download 6 images from server and display on a table in android. What is the fastest way? Should I just store image on my phone instead?

Comment: You want to show images on `ImageView` after downloading that image only. Or, its enough to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If the images never change, store them locally on the phone.
- If they change at regular interval, check the existing dates and download only if necessary.
- If it's unpredictable, check the local ones against the new server images and download only what is necessary.

In short, store what you can locally and download as little as possible.  (*Pretend* that downloading is like washing your clothes: if they are clean, why waste the time and money to wash them again?)